# How to do large combinations with condition in R efficiently?

Tags: r, tidyverse, combinations

Survey shows average score of 4.2 out of 5, with sample size of 14. How do I create a dataframe that provides a combination of results to achieve score of 4.2?

I tried this but it got too big

```
library(tidyverse)

n <- 14
avg <- 4.2
df <- expand.grid(rep(list(c(1:5)),n))
df <- df %>%
rowwise() %>%
mutate(avge = mean(c_across())) %>%
filter(ave >= 4)
```

The aim for this is, given the limited information above, I want to know the distribution of combinations of individual scores and see which combination is more likely to occur and how many low scores + high scores needed to have an average of that score above.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you aiming to achieve with the line `expand.grid(rep(list(c(1:5)),n))`? It looks like you're looking to create every possible combination of scores 1:5 for 14 individuals, which needs 5^14 = ~6 billion possibilities, each with 14 columns. Enumerating them all may push the limits of your RAM.

Comment: "may push the limits" --> for 14 samples, I think that'll take around 350 GB of RAM. That will take a formidable computer.

Comment: @JonSpring, I think that's exactly the problem here ... I'm inferring that they are generalizing the `n` so that they may choose 4 or 14 or 48 or something else, in which case ... we're off to the races wrt memory usage.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'll edit my post to include the aim, perhaps there is another better way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can tolerate doing this randomly, then

```r
set.seed(42) # only so that you get the same results I show here
n <- 14
iter <- 1000000
scores <- integer(0)
while (iter > 0) {
  tmp <- sample(1:5, size = n, replace = TRUE)
  if (mean(tmp) > 4) {
    scores <- tmp
    break
  }
  iter <- iter - 1
}
mean(scores)
# [1] 4.142857
scores
#  [1] 5 3 5 5 5 3 3 5 5 2 5 5 4 3
```

Notes:

- The reason I use `iter` in there is to preclude the possibility of an "infinite" loop. While here it reacts rather quickly and is highly unlikely to go that far, if you change the conditions then it is possible your conditions could be infeasible or just highly improbable. If you don't need this, then remove `iter` and use instead `while (TRUE) ...`; you can always interrupt R with `Escape` (or whichever mechanism your IDE provides).
- The reason I prefill `scores` with an empty vector and use `tmp` is so that you won't accidentally assume that `scores` having values means you have your average. That is, if the constraints are too tight, then you should find nothing, and therefore `scores` should not have values.

FYI: if you're looking for an average of 4.2, two things to note:

- change the conditional to be what you need, such as looking for 4.2 ... ***but*** ...
- looking for floating-point equality is going to bite you hard (see [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518), [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004), and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), I suggest looking within a *tolerance*, perhaps

```r
tol <- 0.02
# ...
  if (abs(mean(tmp) - 4.2) < tol) {
    scores <- tmp
    break
  }
# ...
```

where `tol` is some meaningful number. Unfortunately, using this seed (and my `iter` limit) there is no combination of 14 votes (of 1 to 5) that produce a mean that is within `tol = 0.01` of 4.2:

```r
set.seed(42)
n <- 14
iter <- 100000
scores <- integer(0)
tol <- 0.01
while (iter > 0) {
  tmp <- sample(1:5, size = n, replace = TRUE)
  # if (mean(tmp) > 4) {
  if (abs(mean(tmp) - 4.2) < tol) {
    scores <- tmp
    break
  }
  iter <- iter - 1
}

iter
# [1] 0     # <-- this means the loop exited on the iteration-limit, not something found
scores
# integer(0)
```

if you instead set `tol = 0.02` then you will find something:

```r
tol <- 0.02
# ...
scores
#  [1] 4 4 4 4 4 5 4 5 5 5 3 4 3 5
mean(scores)
# [1] 4.214286
```

Comment: thanks. I think using random sampling might be a good idea. I want a distribution of combinations though. Basic idea is to see which combination is most likely to occur.

Comment: `replicate(10, zz)` this process (10 is the number of replications, ergo 10 possible combinations), and you are likely to get a distribution of possible respondents. (`zz` here is the `while` loop above.) This will return a `matrix`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below

```
n <- 14
avg <- 4.2
repeat{
  x <- sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE)
  if (sum(x) == round(avg * n)) break
}
```

and you will see

```
> x
 [1] 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 5 5 4 1 5 1 4
> mean(x)
[1] 4.214286
```